# Breaking down list of list into dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of list, `s`,  that is the result of querying a database on Fruit, `item[0]` is the name of the fruit, `item[1]` is the whether or not the fruit has seeds, and `item[2]` is whether or not it's edible.

```
s = [['Apple','Yes','Edible'], ['Watermellon','Yes','Yes']]
```

As my actual list is much bigger, I would like a really easy way to reference/return these values. For example, `print my_dict['Apple']['Seeds']` would yield `Yes`

I think my best option would be to create a dictionary, but am looking for recommendations on if this is a good method and how to do this.

I started writing some code but am not sure how to get the second set of headers in place, so my example uses an index instead.

```
my_dict =  {t[0]:t[1:] for t in s}

print my_dict['Apple'][0]
```

Comment: Do you really need to lookup the objects by keys? If not, it would be better to obtain a list of elements that have (name, seeds, edible) fields. Again, `namedtuple` would still be great for this case.

Comment: @rafaelLerm just looking for the most readible/efficient ways of figuring out if a particular fruit has seeds or is edible. Not sure I fully follow you. Still new to python.

Comment: What I mean is that in your use case, will you have just the name of a fruit, and you have to first find the fruit with that name, or will you already have the fruit, and all you need to do is get the attribute?

Comment: Also, is it really necessary to have the attribute return "yes" (a string)? Wouldn't it be better to convert it to a proper boolean value?

Comment: Not sure of the full use case yet. To get away from the fruit example I may have a delivery ID as my key and a ship and delivery date as values. May want to loop through dictionary and figure out days to deliver by subtracting the two dates.  Also, good point about booleans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second set of keys never changes, it would be better to define a proper object with fields. This might seem overkill or to verbose, but there is always `collections.namedtuple` to help.

`namedtuple` creates a new class from a list of field names. That class also supports being initialized by a list. To use your example:

```
import collections

Fruit = collections.namedtuple('Fruit', ['name', 'seeds', 'edible'])
```

This way, you can easily create `Fruit` objects from a list:

```
f = Fruit('Apple', True, False)
# Or, if you already have a list with the values
params = ['Apple', True, False]
f = Fruit(*params)

print f.seed
```

So you can create a list of fruits in a very easy way:

```
s = [['Apple','Yes','Edible'], ['Watermellon','Yes','Yes']]

fruits = [Fruit(*l) for l in s]
```

You really need to have a dictionary indexed by a certain field, it is not much different:

```
s = [['Apple','Yes','Edible'], ['Watermellon','Yes','Yes']]

fruit_dict = {l[0]: Fruit(*l) for l in s}    
print(fruit_dict['Apple'].seeds)
```

`namedtuple`s can be very convenient when transforming lists of values into more easy to use objects (such as when reading a CSV file, which is a case very similar to what you are asking).

Answer (score 5):

```
fruit_map = {
    fruit: {'Seeds': seeds, 'Edible': edible} for fruit, seeds, edible in s}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy

def list_to_dict(lst):
    local = copy.copy(lst) # copied lst to local
    fruit = [i.pop(0) for i in local] # get fruit names

    result = {}
    for i in range(len(local)):
        result[fruit[i]] = local[i]
    return result
```

This returns the dictionary you want.

Comment: This does do the job; although in a *very* un-pythonic way.

Comment: I enjoy your criticism, Raphael. Really. We seem to butt heads at every thread, but I learn much from your critique.